# getting moodle session variables and should work on external site(php)

Tags: php, session, cookies, moodle

I'm developing a web page using the php that will be accessed through a fake moodle course. I don't want to force the user to login twice, so I need access to the moodle session variables in order to know which user is connecting, and log him in automatically.

Both webs are on the same server, but on different directories.

How could I get the logged in user from the other site?

My two websites are on the same domain, but on different paths.

Let's say, for example, that:

- moodle is on localhost/moodle
- my web is on localhost/moodle/cap/login.php

Moodle creates a session cookie that is only valid for localhost/moodle. When the browser is redirected to localhost/myweb, it doesn't send the moodle session cookie.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to include the file `config.php`, and read the content of the global `$USER` and `$SESSION`. However, that assumes that your *fake course* is not built in another system which handles session too.

In fact, you probably want to make your *fake course* in a Moodle plugin or something, as including `config.php` by itself might lead to other form of issues.

Comment: thank you for your response i did that..now i am getting another error..it showing as session time loggedout..please login again..